# TypeORM migrations in Azure Static Web Apps API

Tags: angular, azure, nestjs, typeorm, azure-static-web-app

I’ve written an Azure Static Web App with Angular with an API written with NestJS. I leverage TypeORM for the DB stuff in the API. I’ve set up migrations using TypeORM CLI to run automatically `migrationsRun: true`, but the migrations never get executed on Azure.
Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 0):

We need to create the migration in a standard way with typeorm commands as below:

```
typeorm migration:create -n <migration-name>
```

Also make sure Migration run commands looks like below with all the details:

```
ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run
```

Below is sample .ts file:

```
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";     
export class Book1587131893261 implements MigrationInterface {     
   public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> { 
      await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE book ADD COLUMN price int`); 
   }
   public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> { } 
}
```

Comment: That part I understand and have, but how to make it run automatically on Azure Static Web Apps, because one cannot run the `migration:run` command